# WPF Editable ComboBox with multi-binding displaying object type when selected

Tags: wpf, combobox, multibinding

I've got a editable combobox where I'm using an ItemTemplate that uses MultiBinding. The items displayed when the combobox is expanded display as I expect. However, when an item is selected the text displayed is the object type instead. I've seen posts that suggest overriding ToString(), but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

The object I'm bound to is a collection of UserDetail objects, among other UserDetail has a First and Last Name and an BarcodeID that I'm displaying as a string for each item in the ComboBox. I want to display that same string as the selected item. Instead what I'm seeing is *MyNameSpace.UserDetail*

Here's the xaml for my combobox. Please tell me where I'm going wrong:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="False" Name="myUser" 
          TextBoxBase.TextChanged="myCombo_TextChanged"  
          SelectionChanged="myCombo_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{1}, {0}, {2}">
                        <Binding Path="FirstName" />
                        <Binding Path="LastName" />
                        <Binding Path="BarcodeId" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

FYI, The BarcodeID is for an optional barcode badge reader.

Answer (score 2):

You should only bind text data to a combobox that has IsEditable = true.

Remove `IsEditable="True"`

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Since I am using a USB Barcode reader I think I need the combobox to be editable because the barcode reader looks just like a keyboard to the combobox. BTW, I'm asking this question on behalf of another developer. I've not used a Barcode reader in this fashion myself. FYI, I did try overriding the ToString() method on my EntityFramework entity and that worked as expected. I may have to consider an extension method, assuming I can do overrides in an extension method.

Comment: Did you try? IsEditable does not mean what you think.

Comment: Apologees for abandoning this. The project ended up getting cancelled.

Comment: StackOverflow - the gift that gives to the future!  +1 to @LouisKottmann - this solved my issue.

Answer (score -2):

Set property

> TextSearch.TextPath="your_binding_property_path".

From http://www.shujaat.net/2010/08/wpf-editable-combobox-with-datatemplate.html